# WCF VB serialize twice

Tags: json, vb.net, wcf, serialization, json.net

I have a WCF service with Visual Basic code (below), I need the table that getAdministrationData() returns, and Newtonsoft serializer offers me what I need, so I just don't figure out how to make that the service returns me that, and not an object serialized twice.

```
 <OperationContract()> _
<WebInvoke(Method:="POST", _
RequestFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, _
BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, _
UriTemplate:="getAdministrationDataTree")> _
Public Function getAdministrationDataTree() As String
    Dim myAdmManager As New AdministrationManager()
    Dim model As DataSet = myAdmManager.getAdministrationData()

    Dim json As String = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(model)

    Return json

End Function
```

Hope you guys throw me some light at this, and sorry for the sloppy English.

Answer (score 0):

In your interface class, you should declare definitions as below:-

```
<OperationContract()>
<WebGet(ResponseFormat:=WebMessageFormat.Json, BodyStyle:=WebMessageBodyStyle.Wrapped, UriTemplate:="getAdministrationDataTree")> 
Public Function getAdministrationDataTree() As AdminData
```

You also need to define a data contract like below:-

```
Class AdminData

     <DataMember()>
     Public Property AdminDataField1 as String

     'Define any properties you need

End Class
```

Then in definition class implement your method as below:-

```
Public Function getAdministrationDataTree() As AdminData

    Dim myAdmManager As New AdministrationManager()
    Dim model As DataSet = myAdmManager.getAdministrationData()

    'Create an AdminData object and fill it with values you want to return

     return AdminData


End Function
```

You will receive a JSON object.

If you can provide more details about your the data then I can give you exact code.